# Google Drive API v3 use JSON instead of P12 (Service Account) - Unexpected character

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

> Error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: e. Path
>   '', line 0, position 0.

I am using the Google .Net Client library to access the Google drive API v3 specifically the [Google.Apis.Drive.v3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v3/) package.  I am authorizing using "Service Account" with C#.

Authorization with the p12 key is no problem. However, JSON is recommended and p12 format is maintained for backward compatibility.

I downloaded the JSON file from the Google Developers Console and tried to make the authorization with the following code:

```
    public static Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService AuthenticateServiceAccountJSON(string keyFilePath) {

        // check the file exists
        if (!File.Exists(keyFilePath)) {
            Console.WriteLine("An Error occurred - Key file does not exist");
            return null;
        }

        string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,                  // view and manage your files and documents
                                         DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata,           // view and manage its own configuration data
                                         DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,              // view and manage files created by this app
                                         DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadataReadonly,  // view metadata for files
                                         DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly,          // view files and documents on your drive
                                         DriveService.Scope.DriveScripts };         // modify your app scripts     

        try {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(keyFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
                var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
                if (credential.IsCreateScopedRequired) {
                    credential.CreateScoped(scopes);
                }
                // Create the service.
                Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService service = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "MyDrive",
                });
                return service;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
            return null;

        }
    }
```

I have looked at the JSON file in notepad and it seems encrypted.

> "ewogICJ0eXBlIjogInNlcnZpY2VfYWNjb3VudCIsCiAgInByb2plY3RfaWQiOiAicmFkaWFudC1tZXJjdXJ5LTEyMjkwNyIsCiAgIn.........."

Is it ok to continue using the P12 ?

Comment: they both should work personally I use the p12 file.   This should help https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/659

Comment: Thank you, I 'm going to use the p12.
If there is anyone who can say something about the JSON file, or how it should work then let me know.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me using the JSON credentials file from the Google Developers Console. I am using the Analytics Service, but just swap out the appropriate names for the Drive service:

```
private AnalyticsReportingService service;

public async Task GetAuthorizationByServiceAccount()
    {
        string[] scopes = new string[] { AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly }; // Put your scopes here
        var keyFilePath = AppContext.BaseDirectory + @"KeyFile.json";

        //Console.WriteLine("Key File: " + keyFilePath);

        var stream = new FileStream(keyFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
        credential = credential.CreateScoped(scopes);

        service = new AnalyticsReportingService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "<Your App Name here>",
        });
    }
```

Comment: This was helpful, thanks. I ended up putting the json file in a resource, but the above got me going..

Comment: Do you know how can I extract the Token so I can build a Server-Side authorization and build the google charts? https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are downloading proper file...

```
GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
```

works with JSON file. Its should look something like this:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
---END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": ""
}
```

You can get this file at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials by clicking Download JSON button on the right side of the grid showing client IDs. Just make sure that Type for selected ID is "Service account client".